# What did the White Horse mean for Man-Mountain Gentian? (contains spoilers)

Tags: psychic, urban-fantasy

I have just read Man-Mountain Gentian by Howard Waldrop in the Internet Archive. Second story in the collection [*the Fifth Omni book of science fiction*](https://archive.org/details/fifthomnibookofs0000unse)

Man-Mountain Gentian is a Zen-sumo (a fictional notion, I suppose) wrestler. He is participating to a tournament in Tokyo. His mentor Dr. Wu is described as **not** "one of those cryptic koan-spouting quiet men". But one night Dr Wu calls Man-Mountain Gentian from Tibet. He is on his death bed and, in his last breath, he tells him a koan which I find quite cryptic, about never thinking of the white horse.

From here on there are spoilers. I am not sure that the etiquette here is to put most of a question as spoilers. If not, please edit my post to remove it.

> It happens that the night Dr. Wu called  Man-Mountain Gentian and dies is just before the last match of Man-Mountain Gentian for this tournament (and also his mast match ever since he has decided to retire, but this is not generally known). His opponent in that match, Kudzu Killer has psychic powers. The reader knows that from the way he defeated his opponent in  a previous match. Moreover, through his psychic powers Kudzu Killer ensures that a mediocre baseball player scores a home run under the eyes of his aunt. The latter is none other than Man-Mountain Gentian's wife and she understands what happened. Kudzu Killer tries to convince her to leave Man-Mountain Gentian for him, but he fails. Before she leaves to go back home he tells her one more cryptic sentence : “It is sometimes possible to do more than win” which she says that she'll tell her husband. Which she did, by a letter he gets just before the match.

> As soon as the match begins, Man-Mountain Gentian feels the powerful mental attack by Kudzu Killer. But he manages to resist it (remembering what he is supposed not to think about) and wins the match in an extremely short time. Kudzu Killer, bewildered, mutters "Hooves ?". Many paparazzi ask Man-Mountain Gentian how he did it, but for only one (an old friend) he asks his wife to tell him. She answers “He didn’t think about the white horse”.

I'll accept the best answer that can put together Dr. Wu white horse koan,

> the "more than win" threat, the way Man-Mountain Gentian not only resists Kudzu Killer's psychic attack but wins in less than one second, the Kudzu Killer's "Hooves" mutter, and the wife's answer in a coherent, organised whole.

Incidentally, the story ends with “Gilligan was on his island. All was right with the world.”

Of course I have recognized Browning's Pippa Passes. But why specifically refer to this particular sitcom ? Huxley"s  "Ford's in his flivver; all's well with the world" makes a  lot of sense in "Brave New World" but here I don't see a clear connection.

But this is not a part of my question, just an aside in case anyone can offer an explanation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_a_white_horse_is_not_a_horse might be relevant.

Comment: Although, honestly, it seems more like the old ["Don't think about an elephant"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThoughtAversionFailure) bit.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots The wiki page about white horse vs horse seems indeed relevant. Could you combine it with the other warning to make a coherent whole ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key is the not thinking part. Meditation, often associated with Zen practices, involves emptying one's mind of all thought to experience only the moment. Against a psychic, who is likely to be reading your mind to predict your moves, the key might be to either avoid thinking about your actions, or to distract your opponent with extraneous thoughts. In this case, with Kudzu Killer commenting on hooves, it feels like Man Mountain's tactic was to, rather try to completely empty his mind (a difficult task even at rest) or avoid a suggested intrusive thought (the classic "[Don't think about an elephant](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThoughtAversionFailure)" situation), rather kept his mind on the idea of not thinking about a horse, resulting in the situation were Killer Kudzu, in trying to read his mind, instead got him specifically trying not think about the white horse, and therefore picturing that white horse, rather than what it was that he was going to do.

There is a specific koan mentioned [here](https://illustrativeshortstories.quora.com/The-Monk-and-the-Woman-and-The-White-Horse-As-I-recall-the-version-I-read-presented-this-as-a-Buddhist-lesson-Koan) about not thinking about a white horse.

> This is similar to the lesson, “The White Horse.”
>
> A monk gave to his novitiate for his daily assignment, “Do not think of the white horse.”
>
> As the sun was setting, the novitiate hurried to join the evening meditations and ran up to the monk, saying excitedly, “Sir! I didn’t think of the white horse at all!”
>
> The monk slapped him.

The version told by Dr. Wu has the student asked where he was when he stopped thinking about the white horse, and not being able to answer, which fits with the idea that Man Mountain, by attempting to not think about the white horse, also blanked out any thought of what he was doing.

> The novice Itsu went to the Master and asked him, ‘Master, what is the key to all enlightenment?’
> ‘You must teach yourself never to think of the white horse,’ said the Master.
> Itsu applied himself with all his being. One day while raking gravel, he achieved insight.
> ‘Master! Master!’ yelled Itsu, running to the Master’s quarters. ‘Master, I have made myself not think about the white horse!’
> ‘Quick!’ said the Master. ‘When you were not thinking of the horse, where was Itsu?’
> The novice could make no answer.
> The Master dealt Itsu a smart blow with his staff.
> At this, Itsu was enlightened.

This is unrelated to a more famous philosophic discussion of [whether a white horse is a horse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_a_white_horse_is_not_a_horse).

I believe that Killer Kudzu's "more than win" quote is about inserting the seed of doubt in Man Mountain's mind. Early in the story, he defeated Ground Sloth through psychological destabilization without laying a hand on him. His encounter with Man Mountain's wife has definite undertones of him trying to seduce her. "More than win" is basically saying that he is seeking to not only win the match, but to crush the opponent. Man Mountain, destabilized by Dr. Wu's death, should have been ripe for this approach, but by acting without thought, he left no opening for Killer Kudzu to attack, and instead Kudzu was the one left off-balance by the unexpected thoughts of white horses.

Comment: Well, the koan you mention is very close to the one of Dr. WU, probably there are a few variants. The main difference is that in Dr. Wu koan, after the Master hit  the novice (with his staff, not just slapped) the novice was enlightened. I just upvoted your answer. If no better one is offered in a near future I might accept it, but I hope for one that would integrate the "more than win".

Comment: I thought of Kudzu Killer in terms on acting on minds, not so much reading them, but of course why only one way ? Then the sentence “he knew what it was that he was not supposed to think about” combined with the "white horse is not a horse" could mean Man-Mountain Gentian thought about a (non white) horse kicking Kudzu Killer with his HOOVES. And the latter reading his mind was kicked out of the ring ? Off-balance all right... If no better explanation is offered soon, I'll accept yours.

Comment: I enjoyed reading the story. It's got some nonsensical aspects to it, but it is entertaining and has layers, in my opinion.

Comment: It looks like noone is going to offer a better solution. I just accepted yours.